# AppleScript less than number or greater than number

Tags: applescript

I am having an error in AppleScript when I use less than or greater than operators consecutively. I probably didn't explain that very well, so I will post the code.

```
**set good to false**

**repeat until good = true**
set oneTen to the text returned of (display dialog "Pick a number from 1 through 10" default answer "" buttons {"OK"} default button 1) as number

if oneTen is less than 0 then
    display dialog "below" buttons {""} default button 1
else if oneTen is greater than 10 then
    display dialog "above" buttons {""} default button 1
else
    set good to true
end if
**end repeat**
```

I am trying to take the input from the prompt, and keep the user from entering anything below 0 or above 10. Could you post some code to do this well?

I want something similar to this.

```
**set oneTen to the text returned of (display dialog "Pick a number from 1 through 10" default answer "" buttons {"OK"} default button 1) as number**

**if oneTen is less than 0 or greater than 10 then**

**-- make them do the prompt again**

**end if**
```

Comment: I forgot to say. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
repeat
    set oneTen to the text returned of (display dialog "Pick a number from 1 through 10" default answer "" buttons {"OK"} default button 1) as number

    if oneTen is less than 0 then
        display dialog "below" buttons {""} default button 1
    else if oneTen is greater than 10 then
        display dialog "above" buttons {""} default button 1
    else
        exit repeat
    end if
end repeat
```

Comment: This worked exactly as I wanted it to! I was even able to add on to it so I could expand my code. Thanks! Also, thanks for a speedy answer!